# how to search in document in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch, types, document

i want to search in properties of my_type using elasticsearch..

for example in my_type i have a property named 'folder_applications':

```
"folder_applications":  [
   *[
    "employer_folder_id" => 142
    "status_id" => 140
    "folder" =>  [
      "id" => 142
      "employer_id" => 11
    ]
    "created_at" => "2017-04-12"
    "is_applied" => 1
    "hire_stage_id" => 144
  ],
  **[
  "employer_folder_id" => 7922
  "status_id" => 141
  "folder" =>  [
    "id" => 7922
    "employer_id" => 11
    ]
    "created_at" => "2017-04-12"
    "is_applied" => 1
    "hire_stage_id" => 143
  ]
]

* -> first array
** -> second array
```

here for example i want to search in my_type for object that have status_id => 141;

and when i search this, my search result return hole document with all statuses.. but i want just status_id => 141... not 140 or any other..for example i want to get the folder.id => 7922 && status_id => 141.. and search result just show me the second array of my example.

it happens for the other searches too.. how can i handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `folder_applications` property is [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) you can use [Inner Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) to get only objects inside `folder_applications` array.
Update: Example:

```
{
"query":{
  "nested":{
     "path":"folder_applications",
     "query":{
        "bool":{
           "must":[{"match":{
                    "folder_applications.status_id":141
                 }
              },
              {"nested":{
                    "path":"folder_applications.folder",
                    "query":{
                       "match":{
                          "folder_applications.folder.id":7922
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     "inner_hits":{}
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks @TarasKohut , can you give me an example? yes `folder_applications` has nested type... but i don't know how to write my query.. and because i have bool query too.. i want to combine these together ..